# Poller Task Executor Memory Leak

Tags: spring, spring-integration, dsl, poller

I am building an enterprise application and i am using active mq for internal communication between applications. When i use task executor with my poller AbstractPollingEndpoint and ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor object instances causes memory leak. Object counts in the heap increases even if the application is in idle mode. When i close this part of the code 
`.taskExecutor(outTaskExecutor)`
the problem doesnot occur anymore. But we are preparing for a heavy traffic and we need no provide more threads in order to handle messages. What am i doing wrong? Can you help please? 
Thank you

[Visual VM Heap Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdJwV.png)

```
Executor Service outTaskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

IntegrationFlow jmsOutbound = IntegrationFlows.from(jmsInChannel)
                .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(this.jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory())
                                .destinationExpression("headers['responseQueueName']")
                        , s -> s.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(pollerDelay).taskExecutor(outTaskExecutor)).get())
                .get();
        this.flowContext.registration(jmsOutbound).id("jmsOutbound").register();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look right to have `Executor Service outTaskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);` for every single dynamic flow. Why just don't have it as a *singleton* and share it with all your dynamic flows?

Also pay attention to this description of similar issue in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#async-polling

Plus this SO question: [Memory leak because of receive timeout and task executor out of tune conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57801134/memory-leak-because-of-receive-timeout-and-task-executor-out-of-tune-conf)

Comment: I tried making it singleton but memory leak continued.

Comment: Well, that is just to avoid extra threads with your `new Executor` for every call. The memory leak is described in those links. Not sure why you haven't followed them...